# Upload build folder in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to upload my React app to App Engine using Cloud Build but it upload all source files. Is it possible to only deploy the build folder using Cloud Build pipeline?

**Current pipeline:**

```
steps:
# Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build']
# Deploy
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
  timeout: "1600s"
```

Comment: I'm curious to know - why do you want to deploy the build folder from the local machines? Do you not have different configurations for local and production builds? In which case, you'll have to make sure you first create a production build on your local machine first right? Isn't that tedious?
For instance, I like to work with the development build on my local machine and when I'm ready to commit, I'd just like to push code and let cloud build create a different production build without me having to intervene. In which case what you have in the current pipeline works.

Comment: With my questions, what I'm trying to understand is whether there's any other advantage/tradeoff I'm missing from directly deploying the build folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to only deploy the Build folder and not to upload the others file on App Engine. I think you only have statics file and your app.yaml must only describe how to serve these statics resources.

If so, you can do like this

```
# Deploy
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app.yaml ./build
        cd build
        gcloud app deploy
  timeout: "1600s"
```

It's one solution; others exist. And you should have to update the app.yaml file because the build directory no longer exists in the deployment.

Comment: Posted a couple of comments under the main question - isn't straight up deploying the build folder tedious? (You'd need to explicitly create a production build before deploying each time)
Wouldn't you rather have cloud build do things that aren't in your normal development workflow for you?