# Cloud Build to serve only build folder from React

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm new to google cloud and I'm trying my best to implement CI / CD on a simple MERN stack application.

I was able to set up google cloud build and get the deploy with automatic triggers (from github branch) to work.
I have only one question: in the cloudbuild.yaml file I have inserted several steps, to do first npm install, then npm build and finally deploy. The process is quite slow and it also copies all the code to the server, not just the build folder.

I would like to understand how to configure the file to be able to use the build folder already present in the github repository and do the deploy directly, without further steps.
On the frontend I use react, the only thing I have to do is serve the static index.html file.

Here is my current configuration (only the frontend, to understand)

```
steps:

# Step 0: FRONTEND npm install
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
  dir: 'frontend'
  args: ['install']
  timeout: "5m"

# Step 1: FRONTEND optimized build
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
  dir: 'frontend'
  args: ["run", "build"]
  timeout: "5m"

# Step 2: FRONTEND Deploy cloud app frontend
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "-v", "0-1-2", "app.yaml"]
  dir: 'frontend'
  timeout: "20m"

timeout: 60m
```

In my remote repository I have the build folder ready to use, but I can't figure out how to do the job.

I've also tried something similar to this:
[Upload build folder in Google Cloud Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202804/upload-build-folder-in-google-cloud-build)
without success.

One of the problems is that at the end of the process it appears that cloud build is trying to start npm start.

Finally, I am currently using express to simply serve static files.
Using google cloud can I avoid using it and simply configure the handlers from the app.yaml file?
What web server does it use under the hood to serve files if I don't implement express?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to deploy the build folder, then the link you've provided should do the job. You don't need to run `npm install` and `npm run build` unless you want to to copy all your code and create the build folder using Cloud Build.

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204864/14356361) to @Guillaume (**updated**, assuming the .yaml file is located at the root directory of the project and `build` located at a directory called `frontend`):

```
steps:

# Step 0: FRONTEND copy only build and deploy cloud app frontend
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: bash
  dir: 'frontend'
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
      cd ..
      cp app-production-build.yaml frontend/build
      cd frontend/build
      gcloud app deploy
  timeout: '1600s'
```

By default, Cloud Build uses a directory named `/workspace` as a working directory. If you set the [**dir**](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#dir) field in the build step, the working directory is set to `/workspace/<dir>`. Basically for this build step, Cloud Build's currently on a directory called `frontend` in the root directory of your project/repo.

Also as Guillaume mentioned, you need to update your **app.yaml** URL handlers for this to work. I tested this sample inside the build folder of a [new React app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) and it works for me:

```
runtime: nodejs12

service: frontend-react

handlers:
# Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\..+)$

# Catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

To answer your last question, you can serve static files directly from your app and what you need to do is to configure URL handlers such as [`static_dir`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_static_dir) or [`static_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_static_files).

Take note that each file inside `build/static` are [cached](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) to speed up performance so there could be a delay whenever you make several deployments.

Node.js on App Engine Standard doesn't use any webserver under the hood and you have to set it up by specifying it on your package.json. Here's [some web frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies#installing_a_web_framework) recommended by Google docs.

Comment: Thanks Donnald, can't figure out why it doesn't work. bash: line 1: cd: build: Not a directory 
But the directory is there! I can look at build dir inside github repo

steps:

# Step 0: FRONTEND copy only build and deploy cloud app frontend
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  dir: 'frontend'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app-production-build.yaml ./build
        cd build
        gcloud app deploy
  timeout: "20m"

timeout: 30m

Comment: Updated answer. Also, `timeout` must be specified in seconds so you need to convert 20m to 1200s